# Insert values into a node fields with entity wrapper

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I've tried to use entity wrapper to create a new node and insert the values into the fields, but I get an error.

```
    <?php
$values_entity = array(
  'type' => 'anuncio',
  'uid' => $userid,
  'status' => 1,
  'comment' => 1,
  'promote' => 0,
);
$entity = entity_create('node', $values_entity);
// The entity is now created, but we have not yet simplified use of it.
// Now create an entity_metadata_wrapper around the new node entity
// to make getting and setting values easier
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
// Using the wrapper, we do not have to worry about telling Drupal
// what language we are using. The Entity API handles that for us.
$ewrapper->title->set($values['titulo']);
$ewrapper ->field_fecha_inicio->set($values['fecha_inicio']);
$ewrapper ->field_duraci_n->set($values['duracion']);
$ewrapper ->field_tipo_anuncio->set($values['tipo_anuncio']);
// Now just save the wrapper and the entity
// There is some suggestion that the 'true' argument is necessary to
// the entity save method to circumvent a bug in Entity API. If there is
// such a bug, it almost certainly will get fixed, so make sure to check.
$ewrapper->save();
?>
```

EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. en EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (línea 122 de /opt/lampp/htdocs/tentu/ataria/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I've tried also to insert the values of the field this way:

```
<?php
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->nid = NULL;
    $node->vid = NULL;
    $node->type = "anuncio";
  //    node_object_prepare($node); // Sets some defaults. Invokes hook_prepare() and hook_node_prepare().
      $node->language = $language_url;// Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
      $node->title = $values['titulo'];
      $node->uid = $userid;
      $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
      $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
      $node->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
      $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
      $node->comment = 1; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
      $node->sticky =0;
      $node->field_fecha_inicio[$node->language][]['value'] = $values['fecha_inicio'];
      //$node->field_posicion2[$node->language][]['und'] = $form_state['values']['fecha_inicio'];
      $node->field_duraci_n[$node->language][]['value']= $values['duracion'];
      $node->field_municipio[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $values['municipios'];
      $node->field_tem_tica[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $values['tematicas'];
      $node->field_importe[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['importe'];
      $node->field_texto_anuncio[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['texto'];
      $node->field_g_nero[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['genero'];
      $node->field_ubicacion_anuncio[$node->language][0]['value'] = $ubicacion;
      $node->field_tipo_anuncio [$node->language][0]/*['value']*/= $tipo;
  // Entity reference field
  // 'node' is default,
  // Other possible values are "user" and  "taxonomy_term"
  node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
  node_save($node);
?>
```

I can create the node with the last code, but I can't save the values into the fields. I have seen in my database that the name of the fields isn't for example, field_fecha_inicio, instead, I have field_data_field_fecha_inicio and field_revision_field_fecha_inicio.

How can I insert the values into the fields?

ANSWERD:

```
$node = new stdClass();
    $node->title = $values['titulo'];
    $node->language = $values['idioma'];
    $node->uid = $userid;
    $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
    $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
    $node->comment = 1; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
    $node->sticky = 0;

        $node->type = "anuncio";
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $node->field_texto_anuncio[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = $values['texto'];     
    $node->field_fecha_inicio[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $values['fecha_inicio'];
    $node->field_duraci_n[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $values['duracion'];
    $node->field_municipio[$values['idioma']][]['tid'] = $values['municipios'];
    $node->field_tem_tica[$values['idioma']][]['tid'] = $values['tematicas'];
    $node->field_importe[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $values['importe'];

    $node->field_g_nero[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid']= $values['genero'];
    $node->field_url_del_anuncio[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $values['url'];
    $node->field_ubicacion_anuncio[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = $ubicacion;
    $node->field_tipo_anuncio[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid']= $tipo;

        $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
    node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure in your second code block looks correct to me.

To see what the problem is first create a node of type 'anuncio' using the UI in the backend of Drupal. Now use devel (or just print_r) to inspect the node you just made.

```
dmp(node_load(NEW_NODE_ID));
```

Just before you save your new node you can inspect it too:

```
dpm($node);
```

The new node you are creating needs to match the structure of this node - any differences here tells you what bit is wrong.

EDIT:

In your second code block you don't need these lines:

```
$node->nid = NULL;
$node->vid = NULL;
$node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
$node->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
```

These will all be automatically set so you don't need to set their values.

Also look at the [example here](https://drupal.org/node/1388922).

You need:

```
$node = node_submit($node);
```

and your also missing:

```
node_object_prepare($node);
```

I've edited your code slightly, I think this should work:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = $values['titulo'];
$node->type = "anuncio";
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->language = $language_url;
$node->uid = $userid;
$node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
$node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
$node->comment = 1; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
$node->sticky = 0;

$node->field_fecha_inicio[$node->language][]['value'] = $values['fecha_inicio'];
$node->field_duraci_n[$node->language][]['value']= $values['duracion'];
$node->field_municipio[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $values['municipios'];
$node->field_tem_tica[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $values['tematicas'];
$node->field_importe[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['importe'];
$node->field_texto_anuncio[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['texto'];
$node->field_g_nero[$node->language][0]['value'] = $values['genero'];
$node->field_ubicacion_anuncio[$node->language][0]['value'] = $ubicacion;
$node->field_tipo_anuncio [$node->language][0]/*['value']*/= $tipo;

$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
node_save($node);
```

EDIT 2:

So, if the fields are not getting populated then there is something wrong with this line (let's just focus on 1 field at a time):

```
$node->field_fecha_inicio[$node->language][]['value'] = $values['fecha_inicio'];
```

Initially I would try hard coding the values to get it to work, so see if this line works:

```
$node->field_fecha_inicio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'my test value';
```

Does this line work?

Comment: The structure of the node is the next one: 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vykqA.png

Comment: I've change what you have asked but it doesn't work. Maybe I've done something wrong from the begining. I've created a content type like the next one : 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WKtVo.png . My object is to insert into that fields the data programmaticaly

Comment: I've updated my answer - does the code I've posted work?

Comment: I've insert your code but it doesn't work. I've two question: 1- When I have created the content type I have created the fields into a group, like in the picture that I have added in the second comment. Can this afect when insert the value into the fields? 2- I can only see in the database, for example, field_data_field_fecha_inicio and field_revision_field_fecha_inicio. Maybe I have to insert the value into one of this tables?

Comment: Grouping fields doesn't affect the structure of the node. You can see this by inspecting a node created though the admin interface. You don't need to manually insert into any DB tables that's what the API is for. When you call node_save it will do all of the inserts for you.

Comment: Also what didn't work about the code I posted? Does the node get created at all? Or is it just that some of the fields don't have any data in them?

Comment: The node is created, but I can't see the values of the fields in the database. So, when I do node_load(X) I can see all the information except the data of the fields. The fields are empty. You can see the example in my first comment

Comment: Updated my answer... Getting closer...

Comment: Ok. I've tried and neither. The field is empty. In the database I've only field_data_field_(name) and field_revision_field_(name) tables and bouth are empty.

Comment: So [LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] is not working. Are you sure value is the correct string for the last argument? Some field types use a different value here such as tid, or entity reference. Again compare this to the node you made via the UI to see what the correct identifier is.

Comment: I've seen that instead of LANGUAGE_NONE I had the language of the site, like this [$node->language]. Now I have changed that and I get the next error   [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vykqA.png I've seen also that the third argument values are OK

Comment: Are you sure the $values array is actually populated? If you die on $values['fecha_inicio'] does it have text in it?

Comment: I get the error in field_municipio. In need to insert into this field taxonomy type values

Comment: I don't understand. $values['fecha_inicio'] needs to be a string in order to be able to save it.

Comment: That's true. But what I've than is to insert the field field_texto_anuncio that is string type before fecha_inicio field. And I've insert 'my test value' into that field. I don't change field_fecha_inicio

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure we're getting anywhere and I need to leave soon... I would post a new question saying my field values are not getting saved when I create a node programmatically and see if someone else can help you. Sorry we didn't get to the bottom of it...

Comment: Thanks! If I get the answer I will post it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Hope this function will help you. I am creating a basic node of type page.

```
/**
 * Create a custom node.
 *
 * @param string $type
 *   Type of node (bundle).
 */
function _custom_work_create_a_node($type = 'page') {
  global $user;
  $node = entity_create('node', array(
     'type' => $type,
     'uid' => $user->uid,
    ));
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $wrapper->title->set('Demo title');
  $wrapper->body->value->set('body value');
  $wrapper->save();
}
```